# Is Views update after an Insert(or update) into base tables Immediately

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, view

I have a question about views. Consider we have a view that I insert a record in it's base table. Does my view update after this insert or I should do a `SELECT` to update?

I think my question obvious - is view just a `SELECT` or it's result save in database and if it's base table, so when it's updated it then becomes update?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normal Views are not persisted.  If an updateable view is inserted into then selecting from the view (or the affected underlying tables) will show your results.

Not entirely sure what problem you are trying to solve. Views (non-indexed) suffice for most applications.

Have a look at Indexed Views: [Improving Performance with SQL Server 2008 Indexed Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921%28v=sql.100%29.aspx):

> In the case of a nonindexed view, the portions of the view necessary
>   to solve the query are materialized at run time. Any computations such
>   as joins or aggregations are done during query execution for each
>   query referencing the view. **After a unique clustered index is
>   created on the view, the view's result set is materialized immediately
>   and persisted in physical storage in the database, saving the overhead
>   of performing this costly operation at execution time.**

The typical use of an indexed view is when you have expensive aggregations to perform.

Comment: You say Normal views.Do we have another view type? I want to my data become persist and after every `insert` in my base table my view become update

Comment: Yes, the other type are called Indexed Views

Comment: Does Index views persist data?

Comment: @Nima: yes - indexed views are persisted

Comment: @marc_s Is an indexed view persisted, or is the index on a view persisted?

Comment: @brandon: pls see linked and quoted text

Comment: Haha, actually I overlooked your link but a google search turned up the same page :)  Thanks. +1

Comment: @BrandonMoore: the clustered index on a view **is the data** for that view and that's what's persisted (the clustered index with all its pages --> all your data pagse)

Comment: @marc_s Hmmm... not sure if I am understanding correctly.  The link sounds like the entire view is saved.  Are you saying that persisting the clustered index 'with all its pages' is synonymous to saving the entire view?  Or that the entire view is not necessarily saved?

Comment: @BrandonMoore: the clustered index **IS** the data - so if the clustered index is persisted, in fact, the entire **data** for the view is persisted

Answer (score 2):

Think of a view as a select statement.  Instead of having to write out the entire select statement, you just select the view and it runs that select statement for you.  So yes, anything you do to the underlying tables will automatically be visible in the view.